# CMake: list(REMOVE_ITEM) does not handle escaped \#

Tags: c++, cmake

I work with a dev that uses emacs-- as a result, they sometimes generate swapfiles (call one #cmaketest.cpp) which contain the pound character within a directory marked for

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SOURCES my/dir/*.cpp).
```

In order to prevent these files from being compiled, I would like to be able to:

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM MY_SOURCES \#*)
```

This CMakeFile successfully compiles, but fails on Make, and inspection of the generated Makefile shows references to
#cmaketest.cpp, which it should not.

This is reproducible with the MWE below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12 FATAL_ERROR)
project(libcmaketest)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
list(REMOVE_ITEM TEST_SOURCES \#*)
add_library(cmaketest ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(cmaketest PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

And a file in the PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR named

```
#cmaketest.cpp
```

Am I losing my mind? Am I just failing to escape this character properly, do I fundamentally misunderstand how list(REMOVE_ITEM) works? Is the target_include_directories command the problem? Thanks!

Comment: `do I fundamentally misunderstand how list(REMOVE_ITEM) works?` - Yes, you miss the point of `list(REMOVE_ITEM)` - it removes an item with **exact** value, not the one *matched* to a regular expression. BTW, for check a variable's content you may always print value of the variable with `message()` command,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was losing my mind. FILTER is for removing regex-matched list items, not REMOVE_ITEM.